# Apple submission - In app purchase issue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, submission

I wrote an application in Swift 4.
This application contain an in app purchase.
in itunes connect, the application is properly defined, the in app purchase is properly defined.

When I test this on my iPhone, or iPad: it works well.

I have a button used to get the "full version" of my application.
if I click on this button: 
my application check if the iphone can make purchase
the application get the list of in app purchase item existing for my app (one item here)
if no purchase allowed: a warning is displayed
if purchase authorised: a popup appear to display the price, and ask to the user to accept or not the purchase...
if the user buy the product, it unlock the full feature.
if the user cancel: the application is not unlocked.

Apple validation team cannot do the purchase at all!
when they click on the button to get the full version, nothing happens.

is there anyone having the same kind of issue issue?
any idea of what I could do, test, check, in order to have my in app purchase working locally (with sand boxed account) and not working on apple office side?

thank you for any idea, or help.
my application is blocked in submission process, and I don't know how to fix this, as I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: One question for clarity - are you saying you have one IAP that is a *non-consumable* purchase? A second question about the issue - did Apple give any *specific* details beyond *"Apple validation team cannot do the purchase at all ! when they click on the button to get the full version, nothing happen."*? This sounds kind of strange to me - I have one app the does the same thing. I'm not sure, but I believe Apple actually uses a sandbox - maybe your's - to review your app. Could you have accidentally commented out something in the build you uploaded? Maybe try uploading a new build.

Comment: Have you tried replicating using a release build of your app?

Comment: You should edit your question to show relevant code, but from a UX point of view your application flow is not quite right. You should check for purchase and retrieve available products successfully before even showing/enabling the purchase button. It is better to hide the purchase interface than allow the user to initiate a purchase and then display an alert that they actually can't purchase.

Comment: Hi,yes it is a non consumable purchase. Apple did not give any specific detail. just that they click on "full version" button and nothing happen. same situation on my side open the Apple popup requesting to purchase the full version. no comment on my side in my code. I tried a retail version here ( because now, in app purchase need to validate a first version without the purchase, then submit the in app purchase). and it works on my side, I can see the popup which request to buy the in app purchase.

Comment: I will place here tomorrow a sample of my code. for sure I retreive the in app purchase available before displaying the "full version" button. also I try to restore the purchase, in case of the user has already bought the product. IAlso test if the in app purchase if enable or not. if not, I display a message saying you cannot buy this product, bucause in app purchase is not enabled ( something like that message)

Answer (score 0):

finaly my app was validate.

I added some modal popup, when error, or cancel, or accept occurred.
I believe in this case that the validation team was not seeing the message which were displayed like "Toast" on android.

I close this post in this case.

thanks
Olivier